# How to Change or set custom view for Xsltlistview webpart on Page using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I got several articles on internet for changing Toolbar type of xsltlistview webpart, but I want to update custom view name in "Selected View" dropdownlist using powershell.

[image: list view webpart screenshot]

Comment: Did you figure this out?